# i wrote a currency converter on python and it said that 'money' is not defined when it is. this happened during the multiplication at the end

Tags: python, arrays

```
usd = 2
yen = 1000
gbp = 1.7
eur = 0.75

def again():
    choice = False
    while choice == False:
        money = input("please enter an amount ")
    try:
        int(money)
    except ValueError:
        print("inavlid: numbers only")
        choice == False
    else:
        money = int(money)
        if money >= 1000:
            confirm = input("are you sure y / n").lower()
            if confirm == "y":
                transfer()
            elif confirm == "n":
                again()
            elif confirm != "y" or choice != "n":
                print("invalid options")
                yn()
        else:
            transfer()
def xe1():
    xe = input("do you want currency rates set on this program(yes) or\ndo you want to make your own currency amounts(no)\n")
    if xe == 'yes':
        print ("you have got from ", (money), c, "to ", ((money)/c1*ac1),ac)
        quit()
    elif xe == 'no':
        er = (float(input("what is the exchange rate ")))
        print ("you have got from ", (money), c, "to ", ((money)*er), ac)
        quit()
    else:
        xe1()
```

Comment: That's correct, `money` is not defined inside `xe1` or passed as a parameter to it. I suggest you read and follow a Python tutorial.

Comment: There's a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) that should help.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `money` is indeed not defined inside the `xe1`, because it's scope is limited to the `again()` function. In a better implementation, you can pass money as a parameter for both functions, like this:

```
usd = 2
yen = 1000
gbp = 1.7
eur = 0.75

def again(money):
    choice = False
    while choice == False:
        money = input("please enter an amount ")
    try:
        int(money)
    except ValueError:
        print("inavlid: numbers only")
        choice == False
    else:
        money = int(money)
        if money >= 1000:
            confirm = input("are you sure y / n").lower()
            if confirm == "y":
                transfer()
            elif confirm == "n":
                again(money)
            elif confirm != "y" or choice != "n":
                print("invalid options")
                yn()
        else:
            transfer()
def xe1(money):
    xe = input("do you want currency rates set on this program(yes) or\ndo you want to make your own currency amounts(no)\n")
    if xe == 'yes':
        print ("you have got from ", (money), c, "to ", ((money)/c1*ac1),ac)
        quit()
    elif xe == 'no':
        er = (float(input("what is the exchange rate ")))
        print ("you have got from ", (money), c, "to ", ((money)*er), ac)
        quit()
    else:
        xe1(money)
```